# Is there a list of all the incorrectly labelled MNIST images along with their correct labels?

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, mnist

It seems that its well known that the MNIST handwritten digit dataset contains quite a few examples where the labels are clearly wrong and correspond to the wrong digit, some examples of people looking into this below:

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1912.05283

https://cleanlab.ai/blog/label-errors-image-datasets/

I've tried to find a 'corrected' label list that fixes this, but haven't been able to.

It feels like this is something that probably exists, could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I wasn't aware of these mistakes in the dataset. Very interesting discovery... This might be disapointing but you probably have to clear it yourself using a tool like cleanlab :/ And maybe be the first one to share your corrected version.